# Forcing a scroll trigger after certain points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So what I want to do is have a page that is split into 4 `div`s (let's say 1, 2, 3, and 4). So whenever I try to scroll down after div 1, the page would automatically scroll to div 2; if I try to scroll my mouse down below div 2, it would scroll automatically to div 3; and the same way for div 3 to div 2, etc. I'm sure you have seen something similar to this in some online pages (can't think of any right now but if I find something I will link it).

Basically what it would do is, when you scroll up from a `div` it would animate the transition to the top of the previous `div` on its own.

I tried using jQuery and doing `scrollTop`, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `animate` `scrolltop` and `offset`could do this for you ... show what have you tried at least your basic script -html -css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#div1').offset().top},'slow');
```

The whole code took me a long time to make

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var n=1;
            var classes=$('.class').length;
            $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
                if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
                    n--;
                    n=n<1?1:n;
                } else {
                    n++;
                    n=n>classes?classes:n;
                }
                //to prevent duplicate event
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.class[data-number='+n+']').offset().top},'fast');
                },10);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .class{
            height: 100%;
        }
        .class:nth-child(2n){
            background: red;
        }
        .class:nth-child(2n+1){
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>

    <div class="class" data-number="1" ></div>
    <div class="class" data-number="2" ></div>
    <div class="class" data-number="3" ></div>
    <div class="class" data-number="4" ></div>

    </body>
</html>
```